# Formatting response JSON data using AngularJS & ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have to sent a post request to my node server running localhost:3001. I successfully completed the request and getting the post data in node server but the data is poorly formatted.

AngularJS:

```
function MyCtrl1($scope,$http,$location) {     
    $scope.user = { };
    $scope.login = function() { 

    $http.post("http://localhost:3001/login", 
                $scope.user,
                {'Content-Type':  'application/json'}).success(function(result) {
                    $scope.resultPost = result;
                    $location.path('/');

                }).error(function() {
                    console.log("error");
                });
    };
}
```

Nodejs:

```
app.post('/login', function(req,res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));

    res.end('ok');
});

log : {"{\"username\":\"test\",\"password\":\"pass123\"}":""}
```

is there any way to get a formatted data here?

Comment: I think your want JSON.parse(str);

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON.parse() to parse the body to JavaScript object.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(req.body);
var username = obj.username;
var password = obj.password;
```

Comment: Yes its working ,now i getting 
{ '{"username":"test","password":"pass123"}': '' }
 but how i get the value of username and password from it..

Comment: @Nish If it is successfully converted to object, then you can just access the field using dot notion. Updated the answer.

Comment: when i trying to convert it the node server throws a error SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)